# OpenGL Layered Rendering & Renderbuffer

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, depth, layered

Why exactly does it not work to use a renderbuffer on a layered framebuffer?
I read that if you want to have the depth values you have to use extra textures.
Is that so? Or is there another option to use a renderbuffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is so. Why? Well, the simple answer is that it's defined that way. From the OpenGL spec document, section "Whole Framebuffer Completeness":

> If any framebuffer attachment is layered, all populated attachments must be layered. Additionally, all populated color attachments must be from textures of the same target (three-dimensional, one- or two-dimensional array, cube map, or cube map array textures).

Since there are no layered renderbuffers, you can't use them for layered rendering.